# What would happen if a piece of matter, in our atmosphere, were to suddenly vanish?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, atmospheric-science

What would happen if an object were to suddenly disappear? I mean actually disappear, as in, the space occupied by that object were now completely empty- and a vacuum was left.

If I was holding a basketball in my hand, outside my house, and it vanished. Would the atmosphere's pressure crash down in the one spot? Would there be an explosion?

What would the result of such an event?

EDIT:  I heard something about matter becoming plasma at the center. Is this true? Would there be any physical damage to the surrounding environment?

Comment: Related: http://what-if.xkcd.com/6/

Answer (score 7):

A very small pop - possibly the worlds smallest thunderclap

Surprisingly the average thermal velocity of air molecules (or any ideal gas) is around the speed of sound at that temperature and pressure.
This is about 330m/s at room conditions so the air would rush to fill the 0.3m gap in 1ms

Comment: I heard something about matter becoming plasma at the center. Is this true? Would there be any physical damage to the surrounding environment?

Comment: No - if anything the air would be cooled slightly by the drop in pressure. Removing a basketball is only slightly different from opening the valve on a small vacuum tank